# Calling a function according to class in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Sorry for the question, but I need a little help with my code in JQuery / Javascript

I Have this code emulate a Button from `<a href=""></a>`

Code

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Tourist", new { id = Model.id })" eventsid="@Model.id" class="btn btn-primary newTourist"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</a>
```

I need this code call a function in my `<script></script>` declaration

Declaration

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function clearErrors() {
        $('#msgErrorNewTourist').html('');
        $('#msgError').html('');
    }

    function writeError(control, msg) {
        var err_msg = '<div class="alert-message error"><a class="close" href="#">×</a><p>' + msg + '</p></div>';
        $('#' + control).html(err_msg);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.closeModal').live('click', function () {
            this.remove();
            $('#Modal-Tourist').modal('hide');

        });

        $('#Modal-Tourist form').live('submit', function () {
            clearErrors();

            $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function (data, status) {
                $('#Modal-Tourist').modal('hide');
                $("#eventsDetailsList").html(data);

            }).error(function (error, status, a, b) {
                writeError('msgError', 'Error processing request. Please check errors and try again!');
                $('.modal-body div.alert').html(error.responseText);

            });
            return false;
        });


        function getRequest(url) {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                context: document.body,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.modal-content p.body').html(data);
                    $(this).addClass("done");
                    $('#Modal-Tourist').modal('show');
                    $('#Name').focus();
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    writeError('msgErrorNewTourist', err.responseText);
                }
            });
        }

        $('a.newTourist').live('click', function () {
            alert('Ingreso');
            clearErrors();            
            var id = $(this).attr("eventsid");
            var url = '@Url.Content("~/Tourist/Create")/' + id;

            getRequest(url);

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

But doesn't work, My code running in perfectly state and in certainly moments I put an `alert('working');` in the entire body of the script to verify the code is charge and running...

Sorry for my bad english, anyone can help me and show me the error of my code and why doesn't work the call for the function

```
    $('a.newTourist').live('click', function () {
        alert('Ingreso');
        clearErrors();            
        var id = $(this).attr("eventsid");
        var url = '@Url.Content("~/Tourist/Create")/' + id;

        getRequest(url);

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Unclear what your issue is. Are you saying its the `$('a.newTourist').live('click', function () {` function that is not working? What is `getRequest(url);`? Note `.live()` was depreciated in jquery 1.7 and deleted in 1.9 (do not use it)

Comment: Further to what @StephenMuecke said, you should use jQuery's [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, is my issue, Doesn't work that part, 'my getRequest(url)' is a Content from my PartialView (Html Code) the most part... What use to call the function instead of .live()?

Comment: @FrankFajardo Hi Frank, I change to .on()  but doesn't show the Alert('Ingreso');

Comment: @kingve, It just needs to be `$('a.newTourist').click(function() {` unless your elements with `class="newTourist"` are being added dynamically, in which case it needs to be `$(someParentElement.on('click', '.newTourist', function() {`

Comment: Check your browser console errors. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjxztxLm/1/) that uses on() function.

Comment: @FrankFajardo  I have this error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function$.ajax.success @ 21:398n.Callbacks.j @ jquery-1.11.0.js:2n.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery-1.11.0.js:2x @ jquery-1.11.0.js:4n.ajaxTransport.send.b @ jquery-1.11.0.js:4

Comment: It looks like you are getting errors somewhere else in your javascripts. You should try and fix those.

Comment: @FrankFajardo Ready, Work Now with jQuery.noConflict(); Thanks for the help

Comment: @StephenMuecke This Work Now, thanks you for your help...

Comment: @kingve, good to hear! No worries. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Stephen Muecke and Frank Fajardo for the Help

I Change my `<script></script>`, replace [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and the code work perfectly, I have other issue but I think open other post for that... Thanks guys

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function clearErrors() {
        $('#msgErrorNewTourist').html('');
        $('#alert').html('');
    }

    function writeError(control, msg) {
        var err_msg = '<div class="alert-message error"><a class="close" href="#">×</a><p>' + msg + '</p></div>';
        $('#' + control).html(err_msg);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {                
        $('#Modal-Tourist form').on('submit', function () {            
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Create","Tourist")',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#Modal-Tourist').modal('hide');
                        $("#eventsDetailsList").html(result);
                    },
                    failure: function (err) {
                        writeError('body', 'Wrong Data');
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });

        function getRequest(url) {
            jQuery.noConflict();
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                context: document.body,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.modal-content p.body').html(data);                    
                    $('#Modal-Tourist').modal('show');
                    $('#Name').focus();
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    writeError('msgErrorNewTourist', err.responseText);
                }
            });
        }


        $('a.newTourist').click(function () {           
            var id = $(this).attr("eventsid");
            var url = '@Url.Content("~/Tourist/Create")/' + id;

            getRequest(url);

            return false;

        });
    });
</script>
```